# HasOne associations table is not saving

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi I'm trying to save data across 2 tables (Entries and Conditions) at the same time. Entries has a column called foreign_key which is a relation to the Conditions primary id.

I was testing the saving portion and one of my tables (Conditions) saved but my other table (Entries) did not.

Entry.php

```
protected $_accessible = [
        'metadata' => true,
        'type' => true,
        'foreign_key' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'condition' => true
    ];
```

Condition.php

```
protected $_accessible = [
        'user_id' => true,
        'data' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'user' => true,
        'entry' => true
    ];
```

ConditionsTable.php (where I declared the association)

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('conditions');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);

        $this->hasOne('Entries', [
            'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
            'bindingKey' => 'id',
            'propertyName' => 'entries',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

DataControlellr.php (where I'm testing the saving)

```
        $this->loadModel('Conditions');

        $data = [
            'user_id' => 'b26ee991-a27c-441b-a78b-dd2a1dbf5164',

            'data' => json_encode(['test'=>1,'test2' => 2]),
            'entry' =>[
                'meta' => json_encode(['test'=>1,'test2' => 2]),
                'type' => 'conditions'
            ]
        ];

        $entity = $this->Conditions->newEntity($data,['associated' => 'Entries']);
        //dd($entity);
        dd($this->Conditions->save($entity));
        exit;   
    }
```

So again entries table is not saving a row and conditions is, I believe I'm using the right association (has one) but maybe that not the right logic? Much help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in your data and your association name need to match. You probably want to change your association to this:

```
$this->hasOne('Entries', [
    'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
    'bindingKey' => 'id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

assuming that the class for the `fhir_entries` table is called `EntriesTable`, not `FhirEntriesTable`.

Alternately, leave the association named as it is but change the `propertyName` to `entry` (`hasOne` properties should be singular). Or, change it to `fhir_entry` and the key in the data array from `entry` to `fhir_entry` to match.

Comment: ah yes fhir_entries is Entries will edit that, but yes it works now ty!